# How is strsep working here? Why?

Tags: c, string, pointers, server, strsep

I am trying to learn about writing servers in C and have come across something that is really confusing me. I have been trying to understand some code (not mine). I understand most of it...except this one crucial element in this `parse` function.

Specifically, how is `strsep()` working in the code below?

I thought that `strsep()` finds a point (token?) in which to stop within a string and then chops the end off, storing the remainder within a new variable. Such as finding the `method` within the requestline: `method = strsep(copyofLine, " ");`

This makes sense to me here.

However I don't understand how it works with this:

`//put request-target in abs_path
    abs_path = strsep(copyofLine, "]" + 1);`

Why would there be a `]` in an HTTP request line?

and also here:

`HTTP_version = strsep(copyofLine, "\\");`

Why would there be a backwards slash? Please explain.

Below is the full function. Thank you.

```
/**
 * Parses a request-line, storing its absolute-path at abs_path 
 * and its query string at query, both of which are assumed
 * to be at least of length LimitRequestLine + 1.
 */
bool parse(const char* line, char* abs_path, char* query)
{
    //allocate memory for copy of line
    char** copyofLine = malloc(sizeof(char**));
    //copy line into new variable
    strcpy(*copyofLine, line);
    //allocate memory for method and copy actual method into it
    char* method = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    method = strsep(copyofLine, " ");
    //if method is not get, respond to browser with error 405 and return false
    if (strcasecmp(method, "GET") != 0) {
        error(405);
        return false;
    }
    //put request-target in abs_path
    abs_path = strsep(copyofLine, "]" + 1);
    //if request-target does not begin with /, respond with 501 and return false
    if (abs_path[0] != '/') {
        error(501);
        return false;
    }
    char* HTTP_version = malloc(sizeof(char*));
    HTTP_version = strsep(copyofLine, "\\");
    if(strcasecmp(HTTP_version, "HTTP/1.1") != 0) {
        error(505);
        return false;
    }
    //if request-target contains a "", respond with error 400 and return false
    char* c = abs_path;
    if (strchr("\"", *c)) {
        error(400);
        return false;
    }
    //allocate memory for copy of abs_patg
    char** copyofAbs_path = malloc(sizeof(char**));
    //copy line into new variable
    strcpy(*copyofAbs_path, abs_path);
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(*copyofAbs_path); i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, m = strlen(*copyofAbs_path) - i; j < m; j++) {
            if (*copyofAbs_path[i] == '/' && *copyofAbs_path[i+1] == '?') query[j] = *copyofAbs_path[i+2];
            if (*copyofAbs_path[i] == '/' && *copyofAbs_path[i+1] != '?') query[j] = *copyofAbs_path[i+1];
            // if (strlen(query)) < 1) query = "";
            if (query[j] == '\0') break;
        }
    }

    free(HTTP_version);
    free(c);
    free(method);
    free(copyofLine);
    free(copyofAbs_path);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered that this code is buggy and is doing wrong things? For example, `char** copyofLine = malloc(sizeof(char**)); strcpy(*copyofLine, line);` is just entirely wrong and causes memory corruption. `*copyofLine` is an unintialised value and is not a valid pointer to a char buffer. Doesn't fill one with confidence for any of the rest of the code including the `strsep` calls shown.

Comment: and "]" + 1 looks odd to me. it produces this warning. `warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]` so it points to a string which is after the string "]" in memory, most likely to NULL character if I am thinking right.

Comment: My guess is that the `+1` is supposed to be outside the `strsep` call. To move the string past an opening `[`. That is, should be: `abs_path = strsep(copyofLine, "]")+1;`. We don't actually know the full context of this program. You claim the string is html but it may not be. It may be a json encoded html for example.

Comment: @kaylum Looks like this is the request line received by a web server like `GET /somepage?a=b&c=d HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Concur with the skeptics of the original code. It looks to parse a `GET` request, parsing `GET` first and then parsing everything from that point *up to, and including,* the closing `']'`, and then parsing everything up to the first `'\'` (which it expects to be `"HTTP/1.1"` (How old is this code? Internet RFC 2616  1999). So it appears to be looking for `'GET [some stuff]HTTP/1.1\'` (with the error `"]" + 1` noted in the earlier comments)